# How to process List of List with CompletableFuture in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I have a `List<List<String>>` in java, I want to Process List inside parent List Asynchronously with Fixed thread Pool Example 3. I am trying to use CompletableFuture and Stream in java 8. I am not understanding how to merge these two and how to proceed. PFB Code i have tried so far. In Processor I am just printing it, but i will do DB operations.

So here I am trying to Stream `List<List<String>>` and create number of thread based on the List size but hoe pass the Streamed List as argument to Processor with CompletableFuture.

```
public class CompletableFutureWithList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<List<String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();
        aList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc")));
        aList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("qwe", "poi")));
        System.out.println("helo...");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(aList.size());
        //aList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).
        Processor aProcessor = new Processor();
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        CompletableFuture aComFuture = supplyAsync(() -> aProcessor.processList(tempList), executor);
        try {
            aComFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class Processor {
    public boolean processList(List<String> tempList) {
        for (String string : tempList) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + string);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a CompletableFuture and not simply calling `Future<Boolean> f = excecutor.submit(() -> processList(list))` for each list?

Comment: You may write the simple program which has one thread (simple to debug) and runs this program use executing external processes Apache Commons Exec.

Answer (score 4):

So from what I understand you need to call your processor for each of your `List<String>` inside your `List<List<String>>`

So what you can do is create all the of new threads using `CompletableFuture` then wait for them all to finish and do any processing of the returned values.

So what you could do is something like this

```
List<List<String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();

//Create all CFs
List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> futureList = aList.stream()
            .map(strings -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processList(strings), executor))
            .collect(toList());

//Wait for them all to complete
CompletableFuture.allOf(futureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

//Do processing of the results
Stream<Boolean> booleanStream = futureList.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join);
//Do other stuff you need
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can merge lists of list and completablefuture.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<List<String>> aList = new ArrayList<>();
    aList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc")));
    aList.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("qwe", "poi")));
    System.out.println("hello...");

    Processor aProcessor = new Processor();
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    CompletableFuture aComFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "");

    aList.stream()
            .forEach(list -> aComFuture.thenApply(fn -> aProcessor.processList(list)));

    aComFuture.join();
}

static class Processor {
    public boolean processList(List<String> tempList) {
        for (String string : tempList) {
            System.out.println("Output: " + string);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```